# When using PROC FREQ (etc.) in SAS, it includes the missing values that I created in PROC FORMAT. How do I exclude these missing values?

Tags: sas, missing-data

I created missing values in my data using `PROC FORMAT` like so:

```
proc format;
value ideofmt
   1-2='Lib or Extr Lib'
   3-5='Mod, Slight Lib or Slight Cons'
   6-7='Cons or Extr Cons'
   other=.;
run;
```

When I try to do a goodness of fit test with `PROC FREQ`, it decides to include the `other` values that I coded as missing (`.`). This is my code:

```
proc freq data=sasuser.project2;
table ideology /nocum chisq testp = (0.2 0.6 0.2);
format ideology ideofmt.;
run;
```

I repeatedly get the following error:

```
ERROR: The number of TESTP values does not equal the number of levels. For the table of
ideology, there are 4 levels and 3 TESTP values.
```

This error (and the frequency table output) suggests that `PROC FREQ` still thinks that my missing values are usable for calculations (i.e., that I have 4 values instead of just 3).

My assumption was that `PROC FREQ` by default excluded missing values, so I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of SAS doing something a bit different than you'd expect.

SAS will collapse missing-formatted values into missing, *if* there are any true missings.  This is not because you formatted them as `.` though - it will collapse anything into missing that you format to the same result as missing, even if that's not a missing value.  If there aren't any values with an underlying (unformatted) value of missing, then it gets displayed.

See the following example.  See what happens when you change "Something Else" to "." or " " - nothing!

```
proc format;
value milef
   10-<15 = "Low"
   15-<25 = "Medium"
   25-40  = "High"
   other  = "Something Else";
quit;

proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
  tables mpg_highway;
  format mpg_highway milef.;
run;

data cars;
  set sashelp.cars;
  if mpg_highway = 66 then mpg_highway=.;
run;

proc freq data=cars;
  tables mpg_highway;
  format mpg_highway milef.;
run;
```

In order for your example to work, you need to introduce a single true missing in your data, or else approach it differently (filter out with a WHERE clause anything that doesn't apply is the simplest).

Comment: The `where` clause ended up working for me. Thank you!